# Correct use of option in sequence diagram

Tags: uml, diagram, sequence-diagram

I am trying to use the option condition to show that by pressing [edit, view & delete] UI Buttons, the admin can execute admin privileges. I am not sure if this is the correct way of implementing it. Currently, my thought process is that, if a button is pressed, the button being pressed becomes the opt fragment condition and then I show what happens if it's pressed within the optional fragment. I have nested an alt fragment within the opt fragment to handle errors that can occur. From what I have read and seen, I feel this is a suitable implementation, but any feedback to improve and make this diagram clearer is more than welcome. Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question is, what do you mean with `[click edit user]`? As modeled it is a flag, that determins what option is happening if it is set. Now the first message in this fragment comes from the Admin. That means it is a flag in his or her head. Do you really want to model the brain here?

I rather think, what you want to model is, that there are two possible sequences, either the admin will send the `edit user` message or the `delete user` message. Depending on what he or she does, different things will happen next. This can be expressed by an alternative fragment without guards. Guards are optional and are only misleading when you are dealing with human actors, whose actions are often unpredictable.

Maybe you omitted a `select option` message (that's perfectly legal), whose result could be the flag. But then I don't understand, why the admin will send `edit user`, after she has already selected an option.

In your nested alternative fragment (shown overlapping in your diagram, but I assume that is just a rendering problem), you have the guard `[user found]`. This would probably be a local flag of the `verify username` operation. While it is very much possible, that such a flag exists, it is unnecessary to show it here. The two fragments are distinguishable by their respective first messages `username valid` and `username invalid`. So I recommend to omit the guard.

As a sidenote: The operator for the alternative fragment is abreviated **`alt`**